# How to run more than one query concurrently in hue?

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, hue, apache-tez

If I start the second query, the first one will be killed automatically.

So any config of hue/hive/tez/yarn could control this max concurrency?

Error message:

```
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: 
Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, 
return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. 
Dag received [DAG_TERMINATE, DAG_KILL] in RUNNING state.
Received message to shutdown AM from cnby (auth:SIMPLE) 
at Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, 
vertexId=vertex_1653638109600_4285_2_02, 
diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill while in RUNNING state.
```

Comment: This article explains concurrency in a detailed way and might be helpful for your case https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Hive-Understanding-concurrent-sessions-queue-allocation/ta-p/247407

Answer (score 0):

There is a config in hue:

```
[beeswax]
max_number_of_sessions=10
```

http://cloudera.github.io/hue/latest/administrator/configuration/editor/